# Conexión a base de datos desde C++

Tags: c++

Estoy tratando de estudiar la forma de conectar un programa (en terminal) en C++ con una base de datos. En un principio no importa que tipo de base de datos sea (si MySQL, .mdb). He buscado por todos sitios y no encuentro solución. Lo que más veo es como conectarlo mediante visual studio, y no lo utilizo para nada, solo Sublime. ¿Donde puedo encontrar alguna referencia/guia/documentacion acerca de esto?

Comment: ODBC es lo que buscas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El estándar de C++ no contempla, por el momento, ningún mecanismo estándar para acceder a bases de datos. Es por este motivo que para cubrir esta característica necesitas recurrir a librerías de terceros (o programar tu propio sistema).

Para acceder a las bases de datos tienes a tu disposición multitud de librerías, cada una con sus ventajas e inconvenientes:

- Drivers específicos: Normalmente cada servidor de bases de datos pone a disposición de los programadores una librería que permite conectarse con su motor. Estas librerías pueden estar basadas en ODBC, COM o SQL aunque no tienen esa obligación y pueden proporcionar una interfaz libre. La principal desventaja de este sistema es que necesitas adquirir un driver por cada tipo de base de datos a la que te quieras conectar (MySql, PostgreSql, SQLite, ...)
- Librerías de terceros: Estas librerías suelen presentar una interfaz homogénea para el acceso a diferentes bases de datos. Normalmente estas interfaces se montan sobre los drivers comentados en el punto anterior. Un ejemplo lo encuentras en la librería Qt, que ofrece una interfaz que te permite conectarte a cualquier base de datos... eso sí, solo te proporciona un conjunto limitado de drivers (ver apartado anterior).

Comment: Estoy tratando de compilar un programa para sqlite3, pero cuando trato de compilarlo me saltan errores. Si uso: g++ basededatos.cpp salta el error: basededatos.cpp:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'... Y si uso: g++ basededatos.cpp -lsqlite3 me dice: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsqlite3
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @Jogofus al usar `-l[libreria]` el compilador buscará la librería en un directorio especial donde guarda las propias del sistema. Si no se encuentra en esa carpeta tienes que usar `-L[ruta] -l[libreria]`

Comment: Me descargué de la página de sqlite los siguientes archivos: sqlite3.c, sqlite3.def, sqlite3.h, sqlite3.dll y sqlite3.exe.. Además de unos cuantos más... Que libreria sería?

Comment: @Jogofus ok, pues ahora tienes que compilar los fuentes para crear la librería y después añadir esa librería a tu proyecto... esta es la parte _divertida_ de la programación... es por esto que las librerías de terceros suelen ser más apetecibles

Comment: Entonces, de esos archivos cuales he de compilar para crearla?

Comment: @Jogofus yo probaría primero a enlazar con la dll y, si no es posible, te toca compilar el .c y adjuntarlo a tu proyecto. En cualquier caso necesitas la cabecera para que tu código pueda acceder a las funciones presentes en la DLL

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59495/discussion-between-jogofus-and-eferion).

Answer (score -1):

Podrías hacerlo con sqlite, es mucho más sencillo, puesto que es un archivo.

https://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html

Saludos,

Comment: Tercer comentario tuyo que veo hoy basado en enlaces... por favor, termina con esta práctica.